# ObjFile not properly loading

Tags: opengl, textures, obj

i am losing my mind. I am trying to create an obj parser has a way to learn opengl but i have ran into a brick wall. with DMGregory help i got the textures to work i think but know the mesh just looks like a blob

--Result--

[image: Hmmm]

--Obj parser code--

```
using OpenTK.Mathematics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

using Core.Common.Objects;

namespace Core.Common
{
    public class LoadModel
    {
        public (vertex[] vertices, int[] indices) LoadObj(string path)
        {
            List<Vector3> Positions = new List<Vector3>();
            List<Vector2> texCoords = new List<Vector2>();


            List<int> position_Indices = new List<int>();
            List<int> texture_Indices = new List<int>();


            int[] indicesArray = null;
            vertex[] vertices = null;

            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkBlue;
            Console.WriteLine("loading " + path + " ... ");
            Console.ResetColor();

            string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);

            foreach (string line in lines)
            {
                string[] parts = line.Split(' ');

                switch (parts[0])
                {
                    case "v":
                        Vector3 pos = new Vector3(Convert.ToSingle(parts[1]), Convert.ToSingle(parts[2]), Convert.ToSingle(parts[3]));
                        Positions.Add(pos);
                        break;

                    case "vt":
                        Vector2 texture = new Vector2(float.Parse(parts[1]), float.Parse(parts[2]));
                        texCoords.Add(texture);
                        break;

                    case "f":
                        string[] vertex1 = parts[1].Split('/');
                        string[] vertex2 = parts[2].Split('/');
                        string[] vertex3 = parts[3].Split('/');

                        int index1 = int.Parse(vertex1[0]) - 1;
                        int index2 = int.Parse(vertex2[0]) - 1;
                        int index3 = int.Parse(vertex3[0]) - 1;

                        int texIndex1 = Int32.Parse(vertex1[1]) - 1;
                        int texIndex2 = Int32.Parse(vertex2[1]) - 1;
                        int texIndex3 = Int32.Parse(vertex3[1]) - 1;

                        position_Indices.Add(index1);
                        position_Indices.Add(index2);
                        position_Indices.Add(index3);

                        texture_Indices.Add(texIndex1);
                        texture_Indices.Add(texIndex2);
                        texture_Indices.Add(texIndex3);



                        break;
                }
            }
            
            // bellow is modified\\

            indicesArray = new int[position_Indices.Count];
            vertices = new vertex[position_Indices.Count];

            for (int i = 0; i < vertices.Length; i++)
            {
                vertices[i].pos = Positions[position_Indices[i]];
                vertices[i].tex = texCoords[texture_Indices[i]];
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < position_Indices.Count; i++)
            {
                indicesArray[i] = i;
            }

            foreach (var item in vertices)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.pos);
            }


            return (vertices, indicesArray); //return modeldata and faces
        }




    }
}
```

--Rendering code--

```
using OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL4;
using OpenTK.Mathematics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;


using Core.Common.Objects;
using Core.Render;

namespace Core.Common
{
    public class Loader
    {
        private List<int> vbos = new List<int>();
        private List<int> vaos = new List<int>();
    

        public RawModel loadModel(vertex[] verts, int[] indices, string texPath)
        {
            int vao = createVAO();
            vbos.Add(vao);
            bindIndicesBuffer(indices);
            storeDataInPosAttribList(0, 3, verts, vertex.Stride);
            storeDataInTexAttribList(1, 2, verts, vertex.Stride);
            loadTexture(texPath);
            unbindVAO();
            return new RawModel(vao, indices.Length);
        }

        private int createVAO()
        {
            int vao = GL.GenVertexArray();
            GL.BindVertexArray(vao);
            return vao;
        }

        private void loadTexture(string path)
        {
            Texture texture;
            texture = Texture.LoadFromFile(path);
            texture.Use(TextureUnit.Texture0);
        }
        
        private void storeDataInPosAttribList(int attribNum, int size, vertex[]  verts, int stride)
        {
            int vbo = GL.GenBuffer();
            vbos.Add(vbo);
            GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, vbo);
            // bellow is modified\\
            GL.BufferData(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, stride * Vector3.SizeInBytes, ref verts[0].pos, BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw);
            GL.VertexAttribPointer(attribNum, size, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, 0, 0);
            GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, 0);
        }

        private void storeDataInTexAttribList(int attribNum, int size, vertex[] tex, int stride)
        {
            int vbo = GL.GenBuffer();
            vbos.Add(vbo);
            GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, vbo);
            // bellow is modified\\
            GL.BufferData(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, stride * Vector2.SizeInBytes, ref tex[0].tex, BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw);
            GL.VertexAttribPointer(attribNum, size, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, 0, 0);
            GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, 0);
        }

        private void unbindVAO()
        {
            GL.BindVertexArray(0);
        }

        private void bindIndicesBuffer(int[] indices)
        {
            int vbo = GL.GenBuffer();
            vbos.Add(vbo);
            GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer, vbo);
            GL.BufferData(BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer, indices.Length * sizeof(int), indices, BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw);
        }



        public void cleanUP()
        {
            foreach (var item in vaos)
            {
                GL.DeleteVertexArray(item);
            }

            foreach (var item in vbos)
            {
                GL.DeleteBuffer(item);
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: ok i was looking at the what sort of data was being added to the texture list. and fore some reason its a complete mess.
this is what appears in the console 

(0.250043, 0.5)
(0.5, 0.5)
(0.250043, 0.250043)
(0.5, 0.250043)
(8.7E-05, 0.5)
(0.250043, 0.749957)
(0.749957, 0.5)
(0.5, 0.749957)
(8.7E-05, 0.250043)
(0.250043, 8.7E-05)
(0.250043, 0.999914)
(0.5, 0.999914)
(0.5, 8.7E-05)
(0.749957, 0.250043)

Comment: You construct a vertices array, but don't return it? Remember, there's no guarantee your positions and texture coordinates are in the same order or even have the same number of elements - that's why you build a vertices array that has them properly interleaved.

Comment: this is what happens when i try to use the vertex array
https://imgur.com/a/K3NtvEw

```

Comment: Because your index array is written assuming you're *not* using the vertex array. With the way you're building your vertex array, your index array should just be the whole numbers [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5...]

Comment: sorry for not responding quickly. what would be the best way for me to have the index array use whole numbers?

Comment: `indicesArray[i]  = i`

Comment: i fell like i am bothering you too much and i am really sorry if that's the cause.
but i seem to have run into another problem what do you think might be causing this?
https://imgur.com/a/6s25RiB

Comment: Try updating your question to show your modified code.

Comment: Looks to me like you're advancing along an interleaved array of vector3s and vector2s with a stride that doesn't correctly factor in both parts. Have you tried outputting separate arrays of positions and texture coordinates similar to your previous code, but using the ordering of your vertices array?

Comment: OMG THANK YOU. 
it WORKS https://imgur.com/a/ZTh7HoR
i don't know why i didn't think of that i hope you have a wonderful day :)

Comment: Be sure you post your solution and a description of the fixes you applied to get there as an Answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Special thanks to DMGregory for dealing with my doubts.

I solved my problem by creating a new list of `Vector`s:

```
List<Vector3> out_verts = new List<Vector3>();
List<Vector2> out_uv = new List<Vector2>();
```

Then, I iterate through a list of indices:

```
for (int i = 0; i < position_Indices.Count; i++)
{
    out_verts.Add(Positions[position_Indices[i]]);
    out_uv.Add(texCoords[texture_Indices[i]]);
}
```

I create the indices array with the whole number of the index list:

```
indicesArray = new int[position_Indices.Count];

for (int i = 0; i < position_Indices.Count; i++)
{
    indicesArray[i] = i;
}
```

Finally, the renderer multiplies the lists by the size of the specified vector:

```
GL.BufferData(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, Vector3.SizeInBytes * verts.Count, verts.ToArray(), BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw);
GL.BufferData(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, Vector2.SizeInBytes * tex.Count, tex.ToArray(), BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw);
```

Final result:

[image]

(I'm not very good at explaining things, so I hope all this makes sense.)